# jQuery Slide to right - and replacing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Original HTML:

```
<div id="filler">
    <h2 class="rankings-header">Donor Rankings <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/right_arrow.png" style="right:0; padding-left:10px; cursor:pointer;" id="dr_collapse"></h2>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        $("#dr_collapse").click(function(){
            $("#rankings-list").toggle("slide",{direction:"right"},700);
            $("#filler" ).html( '<h2 class="rankings-header">Donor Rankings <img src="/wp-content/themes/ati/img/left_arrow.png" style="right:0; padding-left:10px; cursor:pointer;" id="dr_collapse"></h2>' );
        });
});
```

For some reason, when I click the image, the slide happens...Once.  And it changes the arrow image.  I can inspect the html and see the changed html.

But when I click it again, nothing happens and no JS errors are thrown

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the expected behavior after the second click? (Disappear, slide back,...?)
Could you maybe add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're replacing the html from the `#filler`, so the DOM element `#dr_collapse` is being re-created, losing its click event.

Instead of `$().click()`, use the event binder `.on()`, in a way that it doesn't depends on the inner DOM element:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("body").on("click", "#dr_collapse", function(){
        $("#rankings-list").toggle("slide",{direction:"right"},700);
        $("#filler" ).html( '<h2 class="rankings-header">Donor Rankings <img src="/wp-content/themes/ati/img/left_arrow.png" style="right:0; padding-left:10px; cursor:pointer;"     id="dr_collapse"></h2>' );
    });
});
```

[**Jquery's .on() docs**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You replace `<div id="filler">` inner HTML code with another one. So `$("#dr_collapse").click` will not work for dynamically created element. Use instead:

```
$(document).on("click", "#dr_collapse", function() {
    ...
```